# Как на C++ в Visual Studio 2015 описать WinAPI экспортные функции для C#?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, dll, vb.net

В старых версиях студии, например в 6.0 я это делал в DEF файле.
Как это делается в современных версиях?
Что бы можно было подключить данную DLL в VB.NET или C#